# Sufficient proof of left exactness of Hom functor

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $A$ be an abelian category. I am wondering if this is sufficient when showing that $\text{Hom}_A(X, -): A \rightarrow \textbf{Ab}$ is left exact.

Suppose $0 \rightarrow A \overset{f}{\rightarrow} B \overset{g}{\rightarrow} C \rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence. For $\text{Hom}_A(X, -)$ to be left exact the below sequence must be exact
$$
0 \rightarrow \text{Hom}_A(X, A) \overset{f_*}{\rightarrow}\text{Hom}_A(X, B)  \overset{g_*}{\rightarrow}\text{Hom}_A(X, B)
$$

I am wondering if it is sufficient to show that $\text{im}f_* = \text{ker}g_*$, i.e. $f_*$ is a kernel of $g_*$. Since the sequence we are working with is in $\textbf{Ab}$, in particular an abelian category, $f_*$ would be a monomorphism since it is a kernel. Moreover, $0 \rightarrow \text{Hom}_A(X, A)$ would be the kernel of $f_*$ since any monomorphism has trivial kernel in an abelian category. Hence we would have exactness at both  $\text{Hom}_A(X, A)$ and $\text{Hom}_A(X, B)$.

Would this be ok? All the proofs I have seen have also proven $f_*$ to be a mono, i.e. injective.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be sufficient. All you have directly shown there is that $\mathrm{im}f_\ast$ is a kernel, which means $\mathrm{im}f_\ast$ is monic... but this is always true. You haven't shown $f_\ast=\mathrm{im}f_\ast\circ\mathrm{coim}f_\ast$ is monic.

However, perhaps surprisingly, it *does* suffice (for proving **left** exactness) to show that $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)$ preserves kernels. This maybe feels like "just one thing" to check and is nicer to do. It's very easy too; if $k:A\to B$ is a kernel of $f:B\to C$ then note for $g:X\to B$ that $f_\ast(g)=fg$ is zero iff. $g$ factors through $k$ by the universal property of kernel, which happens iff. $g$ is in the image of $k_\ast$; it follows $k_\ast=\ker f_\ast$.